# how to replace a string to all 0

Tags: c#, string

I have a string looks like "12345",
How can I replace all Character to '0', so it gotta looks like "00000"
I couldn't use string.replace() function because my string length is not static, also the text is not static either. How can i replace it? I ll give a small code to explain it clearly.

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
var ConvertedStr = str.Replace(str,"00000000");
Console.WriteLine(ConvertedStr);
Console.ReadKey();
//output:
//00000000
```

What I am looking for is ConvertedStr could be the as same lenth as str, with all character is '0'.

Comment: @trix I have a small application that asking replace a string of number all to 0 after button clicked, the number can be 7 digit or 5 digit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just create a new string with the same length and insert only the specified character by using the correct [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_) of the [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

```
string convertedString = new string('0', str.Length);
```

Comment: @CZA  You can also *new it* on itself: `str = new string('0', str.Length);`